# Can I work interactively with the command line?

Tags: deno

As part of a joke that went too far, I'm trying to make black jack in Deno. I'd like to not bring the web into this, but rather use an interactive prompt. I've gone through the [STD Library](https://deno.land/std/io), but I can only seem to find file IO. I was secretly hoping that `prompt` would work to keep this similar to the web, but no luck.

I've done this previously in Node with Readline, Example:

```
export const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});
//...
rl.question(`name? `, (name: string) => {
   // other code
});
```

How can I accept user input in the command line after the application is already running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
import { readLines } from 'https://deno.land/std/io/buffer.ts';

async function question() {
   console.log(question)
   // Listen to stdin input, once a new line is entered return
   for await(const line of readLines(Deno.stdin)) {
      return line;
   }
}

const answer = await question('Name?: ');
console.log(answer);

const answer2 = await question('Age?: ');
console.log(answer2);
```

Comment: While exploring I found I could do something poorly with `Deno.readAll(Deno.stdin)`, Is this the more fleshed out version of that?

Comment: if you use `Deno.readAll` you won't be able to get the answer until you close `stdin`. So using `readLine` is what you need here. You can implement `readLine` logic yourself using `Deno.stdin.read(buf)`